# UnsatifiedLinkError

Tags: java, libreoffice, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Working with Libre Office API and bouncing on a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.star.lib.connections.pipe.PipeConnection.createJNI(Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at com.sun.star.lib.connections.pipe.PipeConnection.createJNI(Native Method)
    at com.sun.star.lib.connections.pipe.PipeConnection.<init>(PipeConnection.java:125)
    at com.sun.star.lib.connections.pipe.pipeConnector.connect(pipeConnector.java:134)
    at com.sun.star.comp.connections.Connector.connect(Connector.java:138)
    at com.sun.star.comp.urlresolver.UrlResolver$_UrlResolver.resolve(UrlResolver.java:120)
    at com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:292)
    at HelloTextTableShape.getRemoteServiceManager(HelloTextTableShape.java:446)
    at HelloTextTableShape.newDocComponent(HelloTextTableShape.java:433)
    at HelloTextTableShape.useWriter(HelloTextTableShape.java:115)
    at HelloTextTableShape.useDocuments(HelloTextTableShape.java:107)
    at HelloTextTableShape.main(HelloTextTableShape.java:98)
CE> Warning: -nologo is deprecated.  Use --nologo instead.
CE> Warning: -nodefault is deprecated.  Use --nodefault instead.
CE> Warning: -norestore is deprecated.  Use --norestore instead.
CE> Warning: -nolockcheck is deprecated.  Use --nolockcheck instead.
CE> Warning: -accept=pipe,name=uno7528184211562854035;urp; is deprecated.  Use --accept=pipe,name=uno7528184211562854035;urp; instead.
```

Anybody knows how to handle this? Can't seem to find a good solution on the internet/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a setting of -Djava.library.path or (if not on WIndows) LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to the JNI library for com.sun.star.lib.connections.pipe.PipeConnection.createJNI(Ljava/lang/String;)I.

Comment: Could u explain how i could fix this properly?

Comment: No, because I don't know enough about OO to tell you what the right pathname is.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libreoffice/urn-link/lib ./start-the-app.sh

That'll allow the native library on Linux.
You have to be aware of the fact that 32bit Java can't be used with 64bit OpenOffice and 64bit Java can't be used with OpenOffice 32bit. I've spent the better part of last days learning that the hard way.

Also the solution on windows with "-Djava.library.path=C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 3.5" works!